# Connection to Mysql from QGis won't draw vector geometries

Tags: mysql, qgis

For year or so, I've worked with QGis 2.18 and Mysql 5.7. Mostly I've worked with visualizing and editing vector data in the tables. All of this was done in Windows 7, and everything was just working out perfectly. Then my computer was upgraded to Windows 10, and suddenly I cannot display any vector geometry data in QGis.

The connection to the database is established as always, I can pick a table to visualize in the "Select vector layers to add..."-dialog, and everything appears fine. It even display the geometry type and number of features as expected.

However, nothing appears in the map window in QGIS. I can see the data in the table and everything, but the geometry is missing. It goes without saying, that this is quite essential in QGIS.

So far, I've tried the following solutions, with some progress:
1. Installing both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of both mysql server and QGIS. 
2. Installing Mysql server version 5.6, and it worked! But sadly I need version 5.7
3. Installing the newest version of QGIS (2.99).
4. Changing the SRID of the geometries to 0 and many other values.

Any experiences on this matter?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue (QGIS version 2.18 as well as version 3.0, MySQL version 5.7). In my case it was solved by applying a feature filter through the **Properties > Source > Provide feature filter** option.

You can just enter your SQL query there, e.g. `SELECT * FROM <table_name>;`.
Don't forget to hit F5 to refresh the canvas.
Hope this helps.